# How to find word from list in column in SQL

Tags: sql, database, teradata

So my exmaple will be like this. Let's say we have table that have company names, but the names are mixed with addresses and sometimes names of the CEO. For example:

| Company |
| --- |
| Some Company C++ Street |
| Alex Another Company JAVA Street |
| Boris Next Company |

And I have a list of companies names that I want to extract from the table. For example I want to get Another Company and Next Company. I know that I can do it like this:

```
Select Company from DB where Company in('Another Company', 'Next Company')
```

but this only works if companies names are without any added stuff. How Can I make it work with example table ? Keep in mind that I want names of the companies hard-coded into query like example above. I'm using Teradata. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `Company LIKE '%Another Company%' OR Company LIKE '%Next Company%'` .. ?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/0KWnj6nPbFdNMqeAQQyX2w)?

Comment: @CaiusJard I think this will be the best. Can you add your comment as an answer ? I will flag It as one.

Comment: `Company LIKE ANY ('%Another Company%', '%Next Company%')` If it's more complex you might use a regex function like REGEXP_SIMILAR